# Media volume is disabled when 'Do not disturb' is active

Tags: 7.0-nougat, volume-control, volume, do-not-disturb

Since I factory reset my Samsung S7 (SM-G930A, Android 7.0), the media volume has become coupled to the 'Do not disturb' state. When 'Do not disturb' is active, either from the toggle or by schedule, the media volume setting becomes greyed out, the slider is fixed where it was, and no media sound can be heard. Are there others experiencing this behavior? Any explanations?

[image: Screenshot Showing Media Volume disabled]

Comment: That's odd. I have Moto G running 7.0 but DND doesn't interfere with media volume.

Comment: I just checked this again, and this behavior has gone away. I guess it was a bug in the build

Comment: This kind of things can never be analyzed. They just come and go like that. I had so many like that 